# Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `mysql`:`3306` | Docker | Prisma

Tags: mysql, docker, docker-compose, prisma

I have a Next js application that I'm trying to dockerize. It shows an error while migrating Prisma. It uses MySQL as a base

docker-compose.yml

```
services:
  mysql:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysql
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_USER=root
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=Discord

    volumes:
      - ./data:/var/lib/mysql/data
    networks:
      - shared-network


  frontend:
    container_name: discord-frontend
    restart: unless-stopped
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
      target: development
    ports:
        - "3000:3000"
    depends_on:
        - mysql
    networks:
        - shared-network

networks:
    shared-network:
```

my Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:18 as development

WORKDIR /usr/app

COPY package*.json .

RUN npm install -g pnpm

RUN pnpm install

COPY . .

RUN npx prisma generate

RUN npx prisma migrate deploy

EXPOSE 3000

CMD ["sh", "-c", "pnpm run dev"]
```

when i run ->   *docker-compose up -d*   is show the following error

```
$ docker-compose up -d
[+] Building 13.0s (12/12) FINISHED                                                                                                                     docker:desktop-linux
 => [frontend internal] load build definition from Dockerfile                                                                                                           0.0s
 => => transferring dockerfile: 263B                                                                                                                                    0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load .dockerignore                                                                                                                              0.1s
 => => transferring context: 71B                                                                                                                                        0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load metadata for docker.io/library/node:18                                                                                                     1.8s
 => [frontend 1/8] FROM docker.io/library/node:18@sha256:f152130c9bb77afd49873a26fcfb6da7971b451ae6db51901fb7e028ccc0ca75                                               0.0s
 => [frontend internal] load build context                                                                                                                              0.2s
 => => transferring context: 100.54kB                                                                                                                                   0.2s
 => CACHED [frontend 2/8] WORKDIR /usr/app                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend 3/8] COPY package*.json .                                                                                                                          0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend 4/8] RUN npm install -g pnpm                                                                                                                       0.0s
 => CACHED [frontend 5/8] RUN pnpm install                                                                                                                              0.0s
 => [frontend 6/8] COPY . .                                                                                                                                             5.0s
 => [frontend 7/8] RUN npx prisma generate                                                                                                                              4.5s
 => ERROR [frontend 8/8] RUN npx prisma migrate deploy                                                                                                                  1.3s
------                                                                                                                                                                       
 > [frontend 8/8] RUN npx prisma migrate deploy:                                                                                                                             
1.258 Environment variables loaded from .env                                                                                                                                 
1.259 Prisma schema loaded from prisma/schema.prisma                                                                                                                         
1.262 Datasource "db": MySQL database "Discord" at "mysql:3306"                                                                                                              
1.307 
1.308 Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `mysql`:`3306`
1.308 
1.308 Please make sure your database server is running at `mysql`:`3306`.
------
failed to solve: process "/bin/sh -c npx prisma migrate deploy" did not complete successfully: exit code: 1
```

my prisma file is give below

```
datasource db {
  provider     = "mysql"
  url          = env("DATABASE_URL")
  relationMode = "prisma"
}
```

inside .env file A

```
DATABASE_URL=mysql://root:password@mysql:3306/Discord
```

Comment: The MySQL container won't be available when building the Dockerfile. Your "migrate deploy" command should probably be run when starting the frontend container.

Comment: First images are built or downloaded, then only containers are started.

Comment: I have moved the migrate deploy command on starting the container
`CMD ["sh", "-c", "npx prisma migrate deploy && pnpm run dev"]`

Comment: Now it shows like this
discord-frontend  | Error: P1001: Can't reach database server at `mysql`:`3306`
discord-frontend  | 
discord-frontend  | Please make sure your database server is running at `mysql`:`3306`.

Comment: MySQL can take some time for it to start up and be ready and your application should be resilient to handle this. Alternatively you can look into using healthchecks and ready state before running your front end container.

Remember: `depends-on` sets the order in which the containers should start and doesn;t wait for the dependent container to be *ready*